# Is there a way to store id value from http response which can be accessed from any page?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-http

I'm new to flutter is there a way to store id value from http response which can be accessed from any page ?. When login the response comes with an ID, I needed that id in various pages in flutter. Is it possible to store it and get the scope from all over the application>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`SharedPreferences`](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to persist application related data. This would be cleared once user clears data of the app.

Comment: when i added the sharedpref like this, ```shared_Id() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('userId', (_login.id).toString());
    print('hello');
  } 
```
I'm getting this error..

** shared_Id() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('userId', (_login.id).toString());
    print('hello');
  } **

Comment: I do not see any error, please edit your question and place your logs over there.

Comment: Also, take a thorough search before making a duplicate of it

Comment: I'm sorry thanks for the information. I got it correct.!